# Gwt TextInputCell doesn't show changed value

Tags: java, gwt

I have a CellTable with a column of TextInputCells.

When i set the value through the UI, manually, the bean is modified.
But, then, when i set the value directly into the bean, i can't make the Table to show the modification. It will always keep what i assigned manually.

Here's my column :

```
FieldUpdater<MyBean, String> myFu = new FieldUpdater<MyBean, String>() {
  @Override
  public void update(int index, MyBean object, String value) {
    object.setValue(value);
  }
};

Column<MyBean, String> myCol = new Column<MyBean, String>(new TextInputCell()) {
  @Override
  public String getValue(MyBean object) {
    return object.getValue();
  }
};
```

Here's the action :

```
@UiHandler("myButton")
public void myButton_onClick(ClickEvent event) {
  for (MyBean my : listOfBeans)
    my.setValue("value");
}
```

I tried to call `table.redraw()` or clearing and refilling the `ListDataProvider`, after the action, but it doesn't change anything.

What can i do ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, i found a (far fetched) way. It's crappy but it works.

```
int inputTextColumnPos; // position of your column

...

@UiHandler("myButton")
public void myButton_onClick(ClickEvent event) {
  for (MyBean my : listOfBeans) {
    my.setValue("value");

    // get the cell you want to update
    TextInputCell cell = (TextInputCell) table.getColumn(inputTextColumnPos).getCell();
    // re-create the view data for the cell because the current one isn't updated
    TextInputCell.ViewData viewData = new TextInputCell.ViewData("value");
    // CRUSH the other one 
    cell.setViewData(my, viewData);
  }

  // because we're never too sure
  table.redraw();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even I had the same problem (I was using `EditTextCell`), but I was unable to find the solution. I tried almost all things. So I came up with an alternative.

I changed that column back to `TextCell` and added `SingleSelectionModel` on the `CellTable.setSelectionModel(SingleSelectionModel)`. I created one `TextBox` and placed it below my `CellTable`. I made it to work like whenever user is changing the selection the `TextBox` will be updated with that column's value. I added `TextBox.addChangeHandler()`, within this method I'm updating the `Bean` and then refreshing the `DataProvider`.
This approach is working fine. Hope it helps. Thanks..