# GWT DataTable TextInputCell is not showing the correct value

Tags: gwt, datagrid, requestfactory

I have a `DataGrid` with a `TextInputCell` column, using a `ListDataProvider`. When the value in a cell is changed I am creating a `RequestContext` and calling `RequestContext#edit` with the original entity for the row that is being edited. I then set the field in the mutable version of the proxy to the value from the edited cell. This all works nicely, and I can save the change successfully to the database. However, on the server I modify the value before saving the change, and send the modified entity (DTO) back to the client. In the `Receiver#onSuccess` method I store the new entity in the list data provider, and then call `ListDataProvider#refresh`. But the value that is shown in the `DataGrid` doesn't change to reflect the modification on the server. I've looked at the value that is supplied to the `TextInputCell#getValue` method, and it is correct, that is, it is the value that contains the modification applied on the server.

I tried creating another column in the grid that is just a `TextCell`, and supplied the same value in `getValue` for that cell; in this case the displayed value is correctly updated by the refresh, reflecting the modified value that was returned from the server.

So, my question is: where does the cell get its value? When I look at the value returned by my `TextInputCell#getValue` method it appears to be the correct value, but that value is not being shown on the screen (the value shown on the screen is the value that was in the proxy object prior to sending the request to the server).

Note: I looked at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12038881/gwt-textinputcell-doesnt-show-changed-value), but it did not work in my situation.

Answer (score 0):

I have a very similar problem.

I have a page showing a grid with two column: the first one has check boxes instead of text.
The value of the check box is given by:

```
public Boolean getValue(Item item) {

    return selectedItems.contains(item);
}
```

When the user checks a check box, I store the value in a map (selectedItems).
At the bottom of the page there is a "Clear" button that reset the map and calls the table redraw, but the status of the check boxes does not revert to the original status (i.e. the check boxes stay selected).

Debugging the code I've found that getValue() returns the correct value, but is like the table caches the cells.

The only workaround I have found, without rebuilding the whole table, was to remove the check boxes' cell and add it again on "Clear".

```
itemsTable.removeColumn(0);
itemsTable.insertColumn(0, makeSelectionColumn());
```

The method makeSelectionColumn() must return a new cell.